# BizTalk Disaster Recovery

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, disaster-recovery, biztalk-2016

We would like to leverage our existing database mirroring and see if it could be used for BizTalk disaster recovery.

Our DBA uses SQL mirroring to different server for DR. The server is located at in a different physical location and has a different IP address. If something happens to the main server, I was told the DBA could easily switch to the mirrored location and business will continue as usual. Our BizTalk databases are mirrored and protected by the scheme described above. This is to set up the context of my question below.

My question is: when disaster strikes, is there a way that I can quickly configure BizTalk to look at the mirrored database? When BizTalk was configured, there was a place to put in the SQL server location. So, I wonder if any BizTalk guru has tried to set up some type of "a dual configuration" to point BizTalk back and forth between the main SQL Server and the mirrored SQL server?

I am aware that BizTalk provides some sort of BizTalk database backup for disaster recovery but I think the backup is just for use of recovering data  back to the point before the disaster strikes. My scenario is perhaps a little bit different: it provides the continuity of the operations during the disaster because BizTalk databases are mirrored. Does my question make sense? I am new to BizTalk, if someone knows a better way to deal with the DR or continuity of operation during the disaster, please advise.

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 Enterprise... The server itself is already mirrored. I was just asking about the Biztalk configuration to switch to the mirrored server. I would think if SQL Server database itself is synched, the switch would not messed up biztalk operations... Anyone has tried this?

Comment: if you are using SQL 2016 Enterprise, i'd suggest you start moving your HADR strategy using Availability Groups (AG) because Biztalk have multiple databases like Sharepoint. You can leverage failing over Groups of databases unlike Mirroring. Mirroring is a deprecated feature so avoid using it in the future. Now the magic will be on the connection string when you failover. i suggest you read the docs provided below answer by @Dijkgraaf. The only gotcha (that i can think of at this moment) is you need to make sure all your logins, jobs are in sync with the other replica secondary servers.

Comment: @dco: Very interesting! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [High Availability using SQL Server Always On Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/high-availability-using-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups)

> **BizTalk Server 2016 supports synchronous-commit mode; asynchronous-commit mode is not supported. For disaster recovery, it is recommended to configure the Backup BizTalk Server job, and use log shipping. See [Backing Up and Restoring BizTalk Server Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/backing-up-and-restoring-biztalk-server-databases) for specific details.**

The issue with mirroring is that BizTalk has multiple databases, if they aren't all restored/mirrored to exactly the same point, then it will cause unexpected behaviour in BizTalk.

Comment: Thank you for your information. So, just to make sure I understand you correctly, if I use log shipping and disaster strikes, biztalk is no longer usable during the disaster. It needs to stay offline until everything goes back to normal, then log shipping will be used to recover the database back to its original state before the disaster strikes. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. Unfotunately you have to make some manual staff before to start on the DR servers( SQL SERVER, BTS Runtime and so on). Have a look on this good wiki. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7897.biztalk-server-disaster-recovery.aspx

Comment: @Hichamveo: The link is awesome and told you what to do to prepare for and recover from disaster. Many thanks!

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: Thank you! Your link helped me greatly.. appreciated it!

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: I understand your explanation above totally. But our DBA does not allow backing up data to a mapped drive and not even on my BizTalk server. So the scheme you discussed above is totally out of the windows. He, however, has mirrored databases (but not using the high availability feature SQL server 2016 provides). My follow up question is: If disaster strikes, BizTalk server is out of commission, but since BT databases are mirrored, after everything is back to normal and the mirrored data restored, would BizTalk be able to continue? Granted it will be out during disaster.

Comment: @user1205746 See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa953743%28v=bts.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and https://www.asp.be/configuring-biztalk-2013-backup-disaster-recovery/    It just is not supported for BizTalk.   You might get it to work, but then if any issues are discovered, Microsoft will not provide support.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: I have a follow up question regarding this topic, please let me know if this warrant a separate question and I will spin it off. Your previous document convinced our DBA to use log shipping for BizTalk backup but he uses his own SQL server backup agent, not the Job provided by Biztalk and he is not disclosing it how he back it up, just saying he is using log shipping not mirroring. Now, when comes time to restore BizTalk after the disaster, what do I need to ask from him for the BizTalk recovery? I am new to BizTalk and he does not know anything about BizTalk.

Comment: @user1205746 If he isn't using the out of the box SQL Agent job and stored procedure, then if any issues are encountered restoring it, you won't be able to get any support from Microsoft.  I would suggest that you carry out a DR exercise and see if it works.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: good idea. Thank you for your suggestion. I'll let him know...